# Code First Migrations with two DataContext

Tags: entity-framework

In my app i have two DataContexts, ApplicationDbContext created by default ,which inherits from IdentityDbContext and DomainContext for my model. Now i am getting some issues when updating the database using Migrations, when i execute 
Add-Migration  to DomainContext in the migration file created is included the code to Drop all the tables related to ApplicationDbContext. I have googled and i have not found any satisfactory answer yet, the only rasonable solution suggest to mingle both DBContexts but that sound weird to me because ApplicationDbContext  inherit from IdentityDbContext.

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base( "DBContextConnString" )
    {
    }
}

    public class DomainContext:DbContext {

    public DomainContext() : base( "DBContextConnString" ) { }

    public DbSet<State> States { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder ) {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema( "Workflow" );
        base.OnModelCreating( modelBuilder );
    }
}
```

One of the The new fetures exposed by EF6 state "Multiple Contexts per Database removes the previous limitation of one Code First model per database when using Migrations or when Code First automatically created the database for you." ([Read it here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2013/10/17/ef6-rtm-available.aspx)). But in practice is a pain to implement this or maybe i am missing something very very obvious.

My question in short, what is the way to go to keep this two different DBContexts living in armony?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation i conclude that the more pragmatic way is to mingle both DbContext into one, so i decide to move my domain entities to IdentityDbContext.